# Can't mount ext4 partition with write permissions

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab

I got a new computer, so I decided to scavenge the old one and use it's 240GiB SSD as my games partition. After I formatted and configured it, I can mount it (and it even auto mounts with fstab), but always as read-only.

I've read countless guides and answers, but all of them addresses ntfs partitions or some other problem with ext4 that I don't have.

These are the steps I used to format and configure the partition:

First, I formatted it with parted, using `sudo parted /dev/sdb` to get into the interactive CLI, then removed all the partitions with `rm`, then `mklabel gpt` to created the partition table, and finally `mkpart primary ext 0G 240G` to create the partition and exited parted. Afterwards, I ran `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` to create the file system.

After that, I created the directory with `sudo mkdir /ssd`, then created a group to access it with `sudo groupadd ssd`, included my user in this group with `sudo usermod -aG ssd $USER` and gave ownership to the new directory to this group with `sudo chown -R :ssd /ssd`.

Finally, I got the UUID of the partition with `blkid` and used it to edit my fstab with `sudoedit /etc/fstab` and just copied the configs from my HD that was already working, only changing the UUID and mount point, and this was my final (and current) fstab:

```
UUID=5AA1-8CE8                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=5a14b7be-2963-4f80-8ea8-383bcdee76fa /              ext4    defaults,noatime,discard 0 1
UUID=fde6cd40-e72e-4377-a849-69816d215940 /hd            ext4    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=99ea0800-f0ef-4d7f-a793-524d2f9afe8c /ssd           ext4    defaults,noatime 0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

After rebooting and checking that the partition was read-only, I unmounted it with `sudo umount /ssd` and checked it with `sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1`, but got no errors:

```
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 11/14655488 files, 1197492/58607360 blocks
```

Finally, I tried remounting it with read-write permissions using `sudo mount -vo exec,rw /ssd`, but it was still mounted as a read-only partition.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is read only?  You didn't show any errors; please add this information to your question.   I suspect it is not read only, but you have not set permissions on it to make it writable to your user.  (Alternately, the disk itself could be damaged and read only in hardware -- but again, you didn't show any errors, so we can't tell.)

Comment: Did you also do a chmod? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138476 & http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html  I just have a shared data partition for my own use & use `sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-rwx /mnt/data`  Note -R is recursion and all lower level folders are also changed. Only run on a data folder, never on a system folder.

Comment: @user10489 Sorry, I really forgot about showing the error `mkdir` threw. You were right, the problem was with the permissions. I just don't know where I went wrong with the permissions since I did the exact same steps for my HD and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drive appears to be properly mounted. There is no indication that it is mounted read only. Then, of course, by default, only the administrator can use it. If desired, the administrator must give write permission to either the entire partition, or selected folders created on the new partition.

Before determining that the partition is mount read only, check whether you can create a folder on that partition as root user:

```
sudo mkdir /ssd/testfolder
```

If that command succeeds, see the folder listed in the output of

```
ls /ssd
```

Make your user owner of the `testfolder` so that user has full access:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /ssd/testfolder
```

`$USER` will automatically be substituted by your own login name. Suply another user name if you want to do this for another user.

Now test if you can create a file on that folder:

```
echo Yes, it worked! > /ssd/testfolder/newfile
cat /ssd/testfolder/newfile
```

The `cat` command should print the contents of the file.

If it does not succeed, then indeed your partition might be mounted read only. That, however, would point to an issue during mounting, because you did not set it up to mount read only.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was actually a permissions problem, my user was incapable of writing to the disk, but I forgot to check if I could with admin privileges. I also don't know where I went wrong with giving ownership to the group `ssd` and adding my user to it.
The thing that really got me is that those are the exact same steps I used to configure my HD and it worked, but when I reproduced it in my SSD I had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check /ssd directory permission, does it having write permission on it or not.
If not then open a terminal and type: chmod -R 770 /ssd